# Emacs leaves terminal in "cursor addressing mode" after exit

Tags: emacs, terminal

When I close 'emacs -nw' with C-x C-c, the terminal often remains in "cursor addressing mode", which causes the scrolling not to work.  According to [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123206/terminal-output-scrolling-is-gone-headless-11-10-server-upgraded-from-10-10), this is due to emacs failing to exit cleanly.  Is there a way to force emacs to exit cleanly every time?

I am using Gnome terminal on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Until you are able to resolve this, try using `reset` to restore functionality.